# qTest API call doesn't upload the attachment when I want to update the test case/test step

Tags: qtestlib, qtest

I face the issue is when I try to use the API to update the test case. it works find for other items, but the attachment is not attached to the test step. I don't know why. any idea for this?
the API I use like this
"put  /api/v3/projects/{projectId}/test-cases/{testcaseId}"  and the body
'''

```
{
...
"test_steps":[
  {
   "description": "test attachemen",
   "expected": "test good",
   "attachments":[
       "name": "qTest_attch_1.txt",
       "data": "dGVxCAedtgWEDRFTD",
       "content_type": "text/plain"
   ]
   }
  }
]
...
}
```

'''